# 7 - Mapping multiple LDAP groups to single Drupal roles using Boolean operators

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I'm attempting to set up fairly complex permissions in D7 based on LDAP group membership, and it would help greatly if there were a way to use Boolean operators to perform the role mapping.

**Some context:**

1. **There are multiple, similar departments:** each has a pool of employees, and each has a manager.
2. **LDAP groups map to departments as well as roles.** The manager of the Finance department belongs to two groups: one that designates the group **Finance_dept**, another that designates the group **Managers**.
3. Managers should have R/W access to parts of the site that **correspond only to their respective departments**; employees should only have R access.

**What I've tried (and ruled out):**

I have the LDAP module configured to provision Drupal roles based on LDAP group membership--that piece works well for one-to-one mappings; e.g.:

- Finance_dept|finance
- Managers|managers

I've tried various iterations of LDAP search filters, to no effect:

- Finance_dept & Managers|finance_managers
- (&(Finance_dept)(Managers))|finance_managers

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until I can find (or someone else posts) a better way to do this, my interim solution is:

1. Set up LDAP group -> Drupal role provisioning as normal.
2. Use the Rules module to assign/revoke another role programmatically on events *User has logged in*, and *Before saving a user account*.

## **Example** (referring to my question above):

### LDAP Provisioning:

- Finance_dept|finance
- Managers|managers

### Create roles manually:

- financemanagers

### Rules:

**Finance_dept + Managers = FinanceManagers**

- *Events:* User has logged in, Before saving a user account
- *Elements:* User has role(s): finance, managers
- *Actions:* Add user role: financemanagers

**Removed from either Finance or Managers**

- *Events:* User has logged in, Before saving a user account
- *Elements:*

  - NOT User has role(s): finance
  - OR
  - NOT User has role(s): managers
- *Actions:* Remove user role: financemanagers

Works for now, but it won't scale well beyond a handful of role combinations.